# Unable to draw on a mutable image android

Tags: android

I am trying to draw lines on an image i am loading from my internal memory using the below mentioned code but it is not working

```
 imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img1.getAbsolutePath()).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
 canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
 paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 paint.setColor(Color.RED);
 imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 imgView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

but when i change the code to :

```
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);;
     canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
     paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
     paint.setColor(Color.RED);
     imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     imgView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

i am able to draw the lines with my finger

Any suggestions ?

*OnTouchCodeListner Function*

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downx = event.getX();
                downy = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upx = event.getX();
                upy = event.getY();
                canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                imgView.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your touch listener code?

Comment: @JasonOfEarth i have updated it on the question

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because it fails to make it mutable. Try using

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img1.getAbsolutePath()),dw,dh);
```